# Detailed click region on image

Tags: java, android, image

I'm trying to create a map app where you can select detailed parts like a country, province, region etc. I have built it to the point where I have a map image and you can pan around, zoom in and out and single tap to show the view coordinates and absolute coordinates on the image. I have very basic functionality say if you click anywhere inside (12, 50) and (80, 120), I can do whatever.

Now I would like to be able to click on certain regions of the map and bring up additional information. The basic click inside this region is not detailed enough to deal with more complex areas (like a country border). What would be a good way to go about working with very detailed click regions?

This is my first app and I'm fairly new to java, any help would be much appreciated!